# Tag synonym information shouldn't be hidden

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-excerpt

#### Case example

There's the tag [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) with the usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt,

> Vim is a free and open-source modal text editor available for most
>   major platforms. It allows high efficiency in many text editing tasks
>   but has a steep learning curve. To learn the basics, run ":help
>   vimtutor".

And there's the tag [viml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viml) with the tag wiki excerpt

> VimL, or VimScript, is the scripting language used to program (and
>   configure) the Vim editor.

But `viml` has been remapped to `vim` and degraded to a synonym. While this is okay in some ways, it seems to have the unfortunate consequence that the `viml` tooltip shows the usage guidance blurb of `vim`, with no mention at all of what `viml` means - this is quite confusing for me as a user. Furthermore, the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vim/info) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/370) links in the `viml` tooltip lead to the tag info for `vim`, while the full tag wiki of `viml` has valuable information not contained in `vim`. Only via the [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page I've been able to dig this information up.

I think this behavior is not ideal and propose two ways to improve it.

- Show the original usage guidance of `viml` in its tooltip and link to its original tag info, or
- include the information about the synonym(s) in the excerpt of the main tag and merge the full tag wikis of the main tag and the synonym(s) as well.

Comment: Aren't synonyms for names that apply to the **same** concept? Either they are different concepts and shouldn't be synonyms, or they are synonyms and should have the same complete description of what they encompass.

Answer (score 4):

Synonyms really should not have a different wiki or excerpt than the main tag. [As Cœur said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358775/tag-synonym-information-shouldnt-be-hidden/358809#comment528583_358775), **the whole idea of a synonym is that the two tags refer to *exactly* the same thing, and thus should be treated identically by the system.**

If [viml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viml) needs a different wiki or usage guidance than [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim), then that suggests they are *not* synonyms and the synonym should be removed.

Or, if they are the same and should be treated identically, then the synonymization process should be taken to the next step: a moderator should *merge* the [viml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viml) tag into the [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) tag.

In this case, the [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) ← [viml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viml) synonym was created by [Carpetsmoker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/660921/carpetsmoker) on January 8, 2017, and then approved either by the community or a moderator (I don't think this information is available). Given Carpetsmoker's expert-level knowledge of Vim, I would be inclined to defer to his judgment here. I shouldn't put words in his mouth, but most likely, the thinking is that there aren't nearly enough questions about the Vim scripting language on Stack Overflow that it would benefit from a separate tag. That just makes the questions about it harder for experts to find. If that's true, the [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) tag wiki should simply be edited to mention VimL.

Comment: You described two cases, but none of them is absolutely true. 1. `viml` does not necessarily need a different wiki or usage guidance (when the ones of `vim` contain all information). 2. `viml` and `vim` are not the same, even if they should be treated identically. -- A third case may well be that there aren't nearly enough questions about the Vim scripting language on Stack Overflow that it would benefit from a separate tag.

Comment: But there is a drawback in merging the wikis - the result would be more lengthy and contain information that someone looking for `viml` in particular doesn't need. It seems to me that it is kind of a misnomer if tag synonyms aren't really synonyms, but rather used for making questions easier to find. And to achieve this goal, the tags would not need to get identical descriptions.

Comment: I just realize that this kind of synonymization makes it **harder** for me, wanting to find questions tagged `viml`, because even if I explicitly search for them, I'm confronted with posts tagged just `vim`. Also I cannot subscribe to a `viml` RSS feed - I'm fed (up) with `vim` posts.

Comment: Regarding _Carpetsmoker's expert-level knowledge of Vim_, which I won't dispute: The whole point isn't just about the `vim` vs. `viml` example, but about the (ab)?use of the so-called tag synonyms in general for making the search for certain questions perhaps easier for some, and harder for others.